Linux-friendly GSM / 4G modem
I have little use of phones, the main use I have for mine is as a 4G modem for my laptop, and sometimes for web searches etc. But I'd really like not to have to depend on the heaviness of Android for this kind of use, so I'm thinking of using a 4G modem USB key which I could plug to my laptop when I need an internet connection.
So I am looking from a Linux-friendly GSM/4G modem, which would also allow me to use AT commands, or to send/receive SMS (and maybe phone calls if possible) with an API (and not only with some proprietary limited web interface). Do that kind of thing exist?
PS: I saw this question, but it did not receive any answer...

Hi Michael, welcome to Hardware Recs! Would you consider switching to a laptop with a build-in modem?

Hi, thank you! Ah, I didn't know that was common. I might be interested, but then I'd just have to be able to disconnect it easily when I'm not using it (for privacy reasons, that's one of the main problems I have with phones).

Hardware disconnect or software disable?

I guess it depends on the modem's behavior? Anything that effectively prevents it to "talk" to GSM antennas would be fine to me (I guess that hardware disable is more reliable but maybe modems obey software disables and unpower themselves, IDK to be honest).
